# Working GRUB configuration for UEFI booting FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, grub2, configuration, boot-loader

I am trying to duel boot x86_64 machine running freeBSD 10.1 using grub. FreeBSD Grub2-efi installation seems going fine but there was no grub.cfg. I manually created grub.cfg. Below are configs I tried and results I got.

My setup :

```
gpart show -l
=>        6  146239733  da0  GPT  (558G)
          6         10       - free -  (40K)
         16        128    1  (null)  (512K)
        144     262144    2  efi  (1.0G) -----> MY ESP
     262288    1048576    3  rootfs  (4.0G) ----> freebsd+ grub are here
    1310864    2097152    4  swap  (8.0G)
    3408016    1048576    5  nextroot  (4.0G)
```

Grub installation command:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/efi/ --bootloader-id=grub --boot-directory=/boot/ --modules="part_gpt part_msdos"
```

Config 1:

```
    menuentry "FreeBSD" {
        insmod ufs2
        insmod bsd
        set root=(hd0,3)
        kfreebsd /boot/loader.efi
   }
```

Result: it's complaining 'invalid a.out header'.

Config 2:

```
    menuentry "FreeBSD" {
        insmod ufs2
        insmod bsd
        set root=(hd0,3)
        kfreebsd /boot/loader
   }
```

Result:Blank screen with white blurr on top. Is it video problem?

Config 3:

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
    insmod ufs2
    insmod bsd
    insmod gfxterm
    insmod font
    insmod videotest
    insmod videoinfo
    set gfxmode=auto
    set kernvt="vt"
    set root=(hd0,3)
    kfreebsd /boot/boot1.efi
}
```

Result again: blank screen with fast changing blur on top.

Config 4:

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
    insmod ufs2
    insmod bsd
    insmod gfxterm
    insmod videotest
    insmod videoinfo
    set gfxmode=auto
    set kernvt="vt"
    set root=(hd0,3)
    chainloader /boot/boot1.efi
}
```

result: signature not matching. Not booting

I am not sure what I'm missing. Can someone please review my grub.cfg? Is there any obvious thing I'm missing? I highly appreciate if anyone can share grub config using for UEFI booting grub on x86.

Comment: You can't put `loader.efi` as an argument to `kfreebsd`. Grub expects to find the name of FreeBSD kernel there, not a boot loader. The FreeBSD kernel is an `a.out` binary; EFI programs are PE (Portable Executable) binaries, thus the error message.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Thanks for your inputs. I have removed .efi . But I am getting blurry screen. By any chance do you have any working grub.cfg  for freebsd?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I'm not that familiar with Freebsd. You could try
changing the line `kfreebsd /boot/loader.efi` to `chainloader
/boot/loader.efi` in you original `menuentry` (while retaining the
.efi suffix). This tells grub2-efi to load and run the Freebsd EFI
boot loader (a EFI program just like grub2-efi). The `kfreebsd`
keyword is for loading the BSD kernel directly, and should take a
kernel image file as parameter. It may not be possible to load the kernel directly under UEFI, you will have to use the Freebsd specific EFI boot loader. But I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 3):

From Linux OS , add the new FreeBSD entry to your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` then regenerate the `grub.cfg` file:

```
rm /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Add the following line to your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` :

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
insmod ufs2
set root=(hd0,gpt3)
kfreebsd /boot/loader
}
```

Run `grub-mkconfig`:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

**Edit**

You must create a `bios-boot` partition (size = 1 M)

From FreeBSD , after installing `grub` from ports collection , install it correctly using the following command:

```
grub-install --modules=part_gpt /dev/ada0
```

Use `gpart show` command to get the right device.

Run the   `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` command , it will generate a `grub.cfg` for you.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @GAD3R.  As I said I am installing freebsd port of grub2-efi from FreeBSD. Post installation I do not see any grub.cfg or grub-mkconfig utility. I have also seen other people reporting missing grub.cfg. Not sure what is the reason. I currently not have access to Linux machine to experiment. I appreciate if you can share generated config here. Thanks again.

Comment: Please run `grub-mkconfig` without option , to verify it

Comment: In my case i have added FreeBSD to Grub installed through linux system

Comment: To save time you can boot linux or freeBSD with supergrubdisk  http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ , from freebsd , mount the ESP partition e,g: `/mnt/esp` then run `grub-install` as montionned on your question with the following option `--efi-directory=/mnt/esp` not the `--efi-directory=/esp/` ( do not forget the `bios-boot` partition. Grub will not correctly installed without it)